# Help with simple RewriteRule problem

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am creating a very small site, 5 pages, in php on apache. I've created the five php files in the top directory, index.php, random.php, etc. I wanted to hide the .php extension, so I put the following into my .htaccess:

`RewriteRule ^random/?$ random.php`

If I visit www.example.com/random I get the page I needed, but if I visit www.example.com/random/ (slash at the end), the css and links are all one directory down, i.e. the server thinks I am in /random/index.php, not at /random.php.

I'm a total noob at RewriteRule, so thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a separate rule for the trailing slash that actually does an HTTP redirect. eg:

```
RewriteRule ^random/$ /random [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^random$ random.php
```

Relative URLs are handled by the browser, so with that trailing slash the browser will get confused.

Most HTTP servers actually do the inverse of this sort of redirect for directory names. That is, if you go to `http://example.com/foo/bar` and `bar` is a directory, you'll be redirected to `/foo/bar/`.